# Script taking photos of 3D models with blender

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, camera

I am trying to emulate the process used to produce the images from 3D models in the smallNORB dataset [https://cs.nyu.edu/~ylclab/data/norb-v1.0-small/. I have a series of 3D models which are in a .stl format.](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eylclab/data/norb-v1.0-small/)

I want to be able to script a process to obtain 2D images of these objects as if they were taken by two cameras under different lighting conditions, evelations and azimuths.

Would this be possible with blender SDK?

Comment: Why not just animate it? Create a bunch of cameras and change the active camera with keyframes, then just have different cameras for the different elevations and change the lights as well. Then just render the animation as an image sequence and repeat for all the models you need.

Comment: Do you use this dataset for research purpose? If so, why don't you use OpenGL? I think Blender is more complicated for this kind of work.